# Python3 , Numpy -- Matrix of Matrix elements

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I want to create a matrix that contains matrix elements. 
So I did the obvious thing and made this:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([1,2,3,1],[3,1,5,1])
B = np.array([1,6,8,9],[9,2,7,1])
E = np.array([A, B],[B, A])
```

But the compiler returns: *TypeError: data type not understood*

What can I do to create such a matrix, because I have really huge matrices and I dont have the time to explicitly write everyone down ?

---

*** Edit 1: ***

*Additional problem that occurred:*

[image]

Instead of getting a 14x14 matrix, I am getting a multidimensional (2,2,7,7) matrix. Where in the simplified version that was my original question , everything is sound. Any ideas why this occurs now?

In this case I have the Amat 7x7, Bmat 7x7 , Emat 14x14, Smat 14x14

---

***Edit 2***

Ok I solved the problem using the np.block() as it was stated in the comments below. Thank you very much.

---

Comment: You got an error on the `A=` line, didn't you?  It didn't even get to the `E` step.  In other words, it's a basic problem with using `np.array`.

Comment: Correcting for the `np.array` syntax, there's still some ambiguity as to what you want.  One answer produces a (4,8) array, another (2,2,2,4).

Comment: One nitpick: you almost certainly want a NumPy *array* (type `ndarray`) rather than a *matrix*. The distinction is important: NumPy does _have_ a matrix type, but it can be awkward to use and isn't always well-integrated with the rest of NumPy or with other NumPy-using libraries. With the `@` operator for matrix-style multiplication available in recent times, there aren't very many good reasons for using the matrix type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want a two-dimensional array of shape `(4, 8)` as a result, it sounds as though you're looking for [`numpy.block`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.block.html). It's available since NumPy 1.13, and as the name suggests, it creates a new array out of blocks, where each block is an existing array.

You also need an extra pair of square brackets in the calls that create `A` and `B`. The signature of [`numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) is:

> array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order='K', subok=False, ndmin=0)

So if you write `np.array([1, 2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 5, 1])` then you're passing two arguments to the `array` function, and the second argument will be interpreted as the `dtype`: i.e., the desired datatype of the elements of the array. This is why you're getting the "data type not understood" error. Instead, you want to pass a nested list-of-lists as the first argument: `np.array([[1, 2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 5, 1]])`.

Putting it all together:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 5, 1]])
>>> B = np.array([[1, 6, 8, 9], [9, 2, 7, 1]])
>>> E = np.block([[A, B], [B, A]])
>>> A
array([[1, 2, 3, 1],
       [3, 1, 5, 1]])
>>> B
array([[1, 6, 8, 9],
       [9, 2, 7, 1]])
>>> E
array([[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 6, 8, 9],
       [3, 1, 5, 1, 9, 2, 7, 1],
       [1, 6, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 1],
       [9, 2, 7, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1]])
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I run the program the Variable Explorer ( I am using Spyder) says that the Size of my original matrix E is (2,2,7,7) instead of the (14,14). What is happening?

Comment: @GeometricalFlows: Read the part about `numpy.block` again.

Answer (score 3):

and welcome to Stack Overflow!

The [`np.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) wants the first argument to be the matrix and the second argument to be the datatype.

Here, you're actually sending in two lists as the first two arguments. Since a list of numbers is not a datatype, it does not understand what you're trying to do. You need to enclose it in a list:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3,1],[3,1,5,1]])
B = np.array([[1,6,8,9],[9,2,7,1]])
E = np.array([[A, B],[B, A]])
```

To send in a datatype, you could do e.g.

`D = np.array([1,2,3,4,5], np.float32)`. 
Now the second argument is an actual datatype, and not a list.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, just missing a few brackets. For a matrix you need to give `np.array` a list of lists.

```
In [4]: import numpy as np
   ...: 
   ...: A = np.array([[1,2,3,1],[3,1,5,1]])
   ...: B = np.array([[1,6,8,9],[9,2,7,1]])
   ...: E = np.array([[A, B],[B, A]], dtype=int)
   ...: 

In [5]: E
Out[5]: 
array([[[[1, 2, 3, 1],
     [3, 1, 5, 1]],

    [[1, 6, 8, 9],
     [9, 2, 7, 1]]],


   [[[1, 6, 8, 9],
     [9, 2, 7, 1]],

    [[1, 2, 3, 1],
     [3, 1, 5, 1]]]])
```

Comment: These are braces: `{}`. They are sometimes called curly brackets. These are brackets: `[]`, sometimes called square brackets when there could be confusion otherwise.

Comment: Awesome that you're making answers! I hope you wouldn't mind just a few pointers? When someone has an error, especially if OP is new on the site, it's often reasonable to assume that the OP does not know what this error means. If you provide links and a description of why the error happens, you can expect to get a lot more rep on your answers! Again: it's great that you're trying to help, and that's only what I'm trying to do too!